torch.nn.functional.softmax giving inaccurate softmax output
I am trying to implement masked self-attention from scratch but when calculating the softmax for the similarity scores I get odd results. I looked at the documentation and other questions posted on here but I still cant figure out what I am doing wrong. Below is a test I set up with the results.
What I tried:
print(sims)
print(torch.nn.functional.softmax(sims, dim=1))

Which gives the following output:
tensor([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
        [ 7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11., 12.],
        [13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18.],
        [19., 20., 21., 22., 23., 24.],
        [25., 26., 27., 28., 29., 30.],
        [31., 32., 33., 34., 35., 36.],
        [37., 38., 39., 40., 41., 42.],
        [43., 44., 45., 46., 47., 48.],
        [49., 50., 51., 52., 53., 54.],
        [55., 56., 57., 58., 59., 60.]])

tensor([[0.0043, 0.0116, 0.0315, 0.0858, 0.2331, 0.6337],
        [0.0043, 0.0116, 0.0315, 0.0858, 0.2331, 0.6337],
        [0.0043, 0.0116, 0.0315, 0.0858, 0.2331, 0.6337],
        [0.0043, 0.0116, 0.0315, 0.0858, 0.2331, 0.6337],
        [0.0043, 0.0116, 0.0315, 0.0858, 0.2331, 0.6337],
        [0.0043, 0.0116, 0.0315, 0.0858, 0.2331, 0.6337],
        [0.0043, 0.0116, 0.0315, 0.0858, 0.2331, 0.6337],
        [0.0043, 0.0116, 0.0315, 0.0858, 0.2331, 0.6337],
        [0.0043, 0.0116, 0.0315, 0.0858, 0.2331, 0.6337],
        [0.0043, 0.0116, 0.0315, 0.0858, 0.2331, 0.6337]])

As an example, I am expecting the output of the softmax function on the first row "sims"
[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.]

to show
[ .047,  .095,  .142,  .19,  .238,  .285]

which would be the accurate softmax attention percentages needed to apply to my value tensor

I think you are confused about what the softmax operation does.
Softmax is defined as softmax(x_i) = exp(x_i) / sum(exp(x_j)). The values you are getting are the correct values:
x = torch.tensor([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.])
x_softmax = exp(x) / exp(x).sum()
print(x_softmax)
> tensor([0.0043, 0.0116, 0.0315, 0.0858, 0.2331, 0.6337])

The values you want ([ .047,  .095,  .142,  .19,  .238,  .285]) are the result of x / x.sum() which is an entirely different operation:
x = torch.tensor([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.])
print(x / x.sum())
> tensor([0.0476, 0.0952, 0.1429, 0.1905, 0.2381, 0.2857])

Also note that softmax gives the same result when the values are shifted by an arbitrary constant (ie softmax(x) = softmax(x-c) when the shift by c is applied to all values along the axis. From a softmax perspective, each row of your sims tensor is just the vector [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.] shifted by different values. This is why each row has the same result post-softmax.
sims_shifted = sims - sims.min(dim=1, keepdim=True)[0]
print(sims_shifted)
> tensor([[0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5.]])
torch.allclose(
    nn.functional.softmax(sims, dim=1),
    nn.functional.softmax(sims_shifted, dim=1)
)
> True

